# AJAX call to C# Web Method to return a List

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Hello I am attempting to call a c# web method that takes 3 string parameters and return a list to use in JSON format. For some reason I cannot get the method to be called and was hoping someone could lend a hand.

The following is my WebMethod within ContentPage.aspx.cs - Date and Stat within statsDataSet are each strings.

```
var myPlayer = new Player();
        var statsDataSet = new List<TodaysTotal>();

        var beginningMonth = (Month)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), startMonth);
        var endingMonth = (Month)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), endMonth);
        var statsRequested = myPlayer.statsBase.GetDateAdjustedData(beginningMonth, endingMonth);

        if (stat.Equals("AVG"))
        {
            statsDataSet.AddRange(statsRequested.Select(day => new TodaysTotal
            {
                Date = day.Date, 
                Stat = day.BA.ToString()
            }));                
        }
        else if (stat.Equals("SLG"))
        {
            statsDataSet.AddRange(statsRequested.Select(day => new TodaysTotal
            {
                Date = day.Date,
                Stat = day.SLG.ToString()
            }));                
        }
        else
        {
            var statCategory = (Stat)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Stat), stat);

            statsDataSet.AddRange(statsRequested.Select(day => new TodaysTotal
            {
                Date = day.Date,
                Stat = day.GetTodaysTotal(statCategory)
            }));                               
        }
        return statsDataSet;
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",                
            url: "ContentPage.aspx/ProcessDetailedStatRequest",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                stat: statCategory //statCategory is a JS string variable, 
                startMonth: startMonth //startMonth is a JS string variable, 
                endMonth: endMonth //endMonth is a JS string variable
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {                                        
                Result = Result.d;
                var data = [];
                for (var i in Result) {
                    var serie = new Array(Result[i].Date, Result[i].Stat);
                    data.push(serie);
                }                                        
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: You getting any error? try `console.log(Result)` in `success` callback.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you load the page `ContentPage.aspx/ProcessDetailedStatRequest` in your browser, what do you get?

Comment: {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: stat.","StackT…ata)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}", responseJSON: Object, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}

Comment: OK, so there's a fault with your C#, so your jQuery is not going to work until that is fixed. Please add more of your c# to your question.

Comment: i added the whole method - i have tested this method and know 'statsDataSet' does contain a List containing fields for Date and Stat, each strings

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your code and step through it.

Comment: as if i haven't tried that

Comment: Well, if you had, you'd be able to say which line it fails on...

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i got it working. The C# needed to be static - and the data i was passing did in fact need to be wrapped in JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `JSON.stringify` from `data`, it expects an `object` and not a `string`.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",                
            url: "ContentPage.aspx/ProcessDetailedStatRequest",
            data: {
                stat: statCategory //statCategory is a JS string variable, 
                startMonth: startMonth //startMonth is a JS string variable, 
                endMonth: endMonth //endMonth is a JS string variable
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {                                        
                Result = Result.d;
                var data = [];
                for (var i in Result) {
                    var serie = new Array(Result[i].Date, Result[i].Stat);
                    data.push(serie);
                }                                        
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

That can be the reason for `500 Internal Server Error`, hoping everything else is fine in the web service.

Comment: its just a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) " - should my method be static maybe? I know when i use pagemethods.methodname() to process them they're static. I'm really reaching now.

Comment: POST http://localhost:2469/ContentPage.aspx/ProcessDetailedStatRequest 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: ive debugged though it by just calling it through PageMethods.ProcessDetailedStatRequest and the list im returning has all the data i expect, i just don't know how to use it through PageMethods and that's why i'm trying the ajax call.

Comment: I believe your method should be static, also, on this example the JS object is surrounded by single quote, not sure why though, also make sure your method is decorated by "WebMethod" of course. 

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: Invalid JSON primitive: stat. - it doesn't look like it likes my parameter im passing